# Testing XMLHttpRequest on local server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a xhr request. I'm trying testing code on my local server.

```
GetMetaData: function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "../?/?.asmx/GetData", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8;');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            "args": JSON.stringify({
                method: "?",
                factors: "?",
                lcid: app.ResponseParamsValues.lcid,
            })
        }));

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                var response = (JSON.parse(this.responseText).d);
                app.variables.metaValues = response.Result;
            }
            if (this.status != 200) {
                console.log('error: ' + (this.status ? this.statusText : '?'));
            }
        };
    }
```

I'm trying change response to my .json file on local server. But it doesn't work

```
GetMetaData: function () {
      return "../../data/data.json";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use it for testing on my local server

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "example.json", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8;');
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (this.readyState == 4) {
          var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

          //some actions with the response
    }

    if (this.status != 200) {
          console.log('error: ' + (this.status ? this.statusText : 'request failed'));
    }
};
```